# What is the best (and safest) way to get the contents of a webpages h1 tag using PHP?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am using PHP's `get_meta_tags()` function to get the meta tags for different webpages. I want to know what is the best way to get the contents of the `<h1>` tag of a webpage. Should I use `file_get_contents()`, or is there a better way?

Comment: "Should I use `file_get_contents()`" --- this part has nothing to do with `h1` extraction process

Comment: `Should I use file_get_contents()` - I would use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Answer (score 4):

Yes I would use:

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://example.com');
$matches = array();
preg_match( '#<h1>(.*?)</h1>#', $page, $matches );
```

You information should be in `$matches`

Comment: Someone has to link to this. :-) [Parsing HTML with RegEx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: I can't up-vote. It might "work", but it can just go downhill .. I have bad experiences with other developers polluting code with stuff that "works".

Answer (score 1):

`file_get_contents()` can work to get you the contents of the page. Once you have the contents, how you extract the `h1` tag is up to you.

You could try a simple regular expression to return the contents of the first `h1` tag:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match_all("/<h1>(.*?)<\/h1>/", $contents, $matches);
$h1 = $matches[1];
```

However, I prefer using a DOM parser when working with HTML. The [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/index.htm) is pretty easy to use. Something like:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$html = str_get_html($contents);
$h1 = $html->find("h1")[0];
```

**Note**: I did not test these code snippets. Just some samples to get you started.

Comment: You have to use `$html->find("h1", 0);`.

Answer (score 0):

The `<h1>` tags aren't meta tags, so you can't use the `get_meta_tags()` function. Meta tags in a HTML document are tags in the `<head>` section that contain information about the page, not the content itself.

[PHP.DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) is probably the best way to get the information you want. Here is a [link](http://www.php4every1.com/tutorials/php-domdocument-tutorial/) to a decent tutorial that should get you started nicely.

Comment: "I am using PHP's get_meta_tags() function to get the meta tags for different webpages" --- it's just a piece of irrelevant info :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net).

Code:

```
<?php
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$raw = '<h1>blah</h1>'; // Set the raw HTML of the webpage here
$html = str_get_html($raw);
$h1 = $html->find('h1', 0)->plaintext;
echo $h1;
?>
```